# using x:Uid for a button

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

im trying to localize my application. I learned how to use resource files resw, and everything is smooth with textblocks. But for buttons i couldn't use x:Uid, i get exception saying

> WinRT information: Unable to resolve property 'Text' while processing
>   properties for Uid 'Continue'. [Line: 43 Position: 82]

But I could use same x:Uid (read as 'Continue') for a textblock. 
can someone tell me what am i missing? As of now i'm not using styles for button, but i will use.

xaml:

```
 <Button Style="{StaticResource DarkButton}" x:Uid="Continue"  
 Content="Default value" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
 VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,14,14" Height="48" Width="140" 
 Name="button2" Click="button2_Click_1" IsEnabled="False" />
```

> xml

```
  <data name="Continue.Content" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Continue</value>
  </data>
```

I added Continue.Text\Continue.Content in resw, along with Continue.Width

Comment: I'm guessing "Continue" is a button or similar based on its name. Buttons don't have a `Text` property, they have [`Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx). You want to localize the Content property, not the Text property.

Comment: How do i do that? changing in resw didn't help

Comment: Can you post the relevant XML of your RESX?

Comment: updated in question, thanks

Comment: Did you totally get rid of Continue.Text in your resw OR did you ADD Continue.Content - your trailing comment there is a bit ambiguous. You want only Continue.Content.

Comment: i removed Continue.text in resw file and addede Continue.Content, still it fails with same error. I understand that i've to localize Content, instead of Text but not sure why program looks for Text property for Continue button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jim and vcsjones are correct.  Continue.Content would be the key in your RESW file.  If there is a Continue.Text value in there it will fail with the error you see.

The localization merge in the parser will fail if it cannot assign to a property and that is what you are seeing.

Comment: thanks again, the problem is i've two resw files en and en-us. All this time, i was changing at only one place.
But with this approach, i may not be able to use same string for different type objects(one has text, another has content).